# while installing the gitlab-ce in openshift using gitlab operators I am facing the following issue. Anyone help me "4 pod has unbound immediate PVC"

Tags: gitlab, openshift, gitlab-ce

[root@bastion ~]# kubectl describe po gitlab-ui-gitaly-0 -n gitlab-system
Name:           gitlab-ui-gitaly-0
Namespace:      gitlab-system
Priority:       0
Node:           
Labels:         app=gitaly
app.kubernetes.io/component=gitaly
app.kubernetes.io/instance=gitlab-ui-gitaly
app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=gitlab-operator
app.kubernetes.io/name=gitlab-ui
app.kubernetes.io/part-of=gitlab
chart=gitaly-5.7.1
controller-revision-hash=gitlab-ui-gitaly-7f87fb98bd
heritage=Helm
release=gitlab-ui
statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=gitlab-ui-gitaly-0
Annotations:    checksum/config: acaaa7500c4f82921dc017dbfb173dd7ee4a44f9704b5bd0bceda31702f06d3d
gitlab.com/prometheus_port: 9236
gitlab.com/prometheus_scrape: true
openshift.io/scc: anyuid
prometheus.io/port: 9236
prometheus.io/scrape: true
Status:         Pending
IP:
IPs:            
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/gitlab-ui-gitaly
Init Containers:
certificates:
Image:      registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/build/cng/alpine-certificates:20191127-r2
Port:       
Host Port:  
Requests:
cpu:        50m
Environment:  
Mounts:
/etc/ssl/certs from etc-ssl-certs (rw)
configure:
Image:      registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-native/mirror/images/busybox:latest
Port:       
Host Port:  
Command:
sh
/config/configure
Requests:
cpu:        50m
Environment:  
Mounts:
/config from gitaly-config (ro)
/init-config from init-gitaly-secrets (ro)
/init-secrets from gitaly-secrets (rw)
Containers:
gitaly:
Image:       registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/build/cng/gitaly:v14.7.1
Ports:       8075/TCP, 9236/TCP
Host Ports:  0/TCP, 0/TCP
Requests:
cpu:      100m
memory:   200Mi
Liveness:   exec [/scripts/healthcheck] delay=30s timeout=3s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
Readiness:  exec [/scripts/healthcheck] delay=10s timeout=3s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
Environment:
CONFIG_TEMPLATE_DIRECTORY:  /etc/gitaly/templates
CONFIG_DIRECTORY:           /etc/gitaly
GITALY_CONFIG_FILE:         /etc/gitaly/config.toml
SSL_CERT_DIR:               /etc/ssl/certs
Mounts:
/etc/gitaly/templates from gitaly-config (rw)
/etc/gitlab-secrets from gitaly-secrets (ro)
/etc/ssl/certs/ from etc-ssl-certs (ro)
/home/git/repositories from repo-data (rw)
Conditions:
Type           Status
PodScheduled   False
Volumes:
repo-data:
Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
ClaimName:  repo-data-gitlab-ui-gitaly-0
ReadOnly:   false
gitaly-config:
Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
Name:      gitlab-ui-gitaly
Optional:  false
gitaly-secrets:
Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
Medium:     Memory
SizeLimit:  
init-gitaly-secrets:
Type:                Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
SecretName:          gitlab-ui-gitaly-secret
SecretOptionalName:  
SecretName:          gitlab-ui-gitlab-shell-secret
SecretOptionalName:  
etc-ssl-certs:
Type:        EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
Medium:      Memory
SizeLimit:   
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
**Events:

Type     Reason            Age    From               Message

----     ------            ----   ----               -------

Warning  FailedScheduling  82m    default-scheduler  0/4 nodes are available: 4 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.

Warning  FailedScheduling  82m    default-scheduler  0/4 nodes are available: 4 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.

Warning  FailedScheduling  66m    default-scheduler  0/4 nodes are available: 4 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.

Warning  FailedScheduling  65m    default-scheduler  0/4 nodes are available: 4 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.

Warning  FailedScheduling  52m    default-scheduler  0/4 nodes are available: 4 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.

Warning  FailedScheduling  4m44s  default-scheduler  0/4 nodes are available: 4 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.

Warning  FailedScheduling  6s     default-scheduler  0/4 nodes are available: 4 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.

Warning  FailedScheduling  2m1s   default-scheduler  0/4 nodes are available: 4 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.

Warning  FailedScheduling  48s    default-scheduler  0/4 nodes are available: 4 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.**

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the following issue due to PVC storage class and pods are showing pending status.
but I am follow this link
https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/installation/operator.html

[image]

[image]